# Automating user creation with information from text file

Tags: bash, scripts, adduser

I have one `txt` in this format:

```
dfs /home/dfs ashik karki
```

so now i need a bash script for reading the each word from the text file and what i am going to do is i want to automate adduser and generate random password. Here the user is dfs and home directory is /home/dfs and ashik karki as a comment. So how can i automate this process bu writing a bash script? 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the comment ?

Comment: I felt free to change your title, as reading words from txt file is not the main task here and would have many duplicates on this site  ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```bsh
# Login as root if necessary
sudo su

# Create your own adduser function to automate the process
adduser2() {
    # add the user
    adduser --home $2 --disabled-login $1
    # Create a password (change 10 to the password length you want)
    local pass=$(openssl rand -base64 10)
    # Change the password
    echo -e "$pass\n$pass" | passwd $1
    # Print information
    echo "Password for user $1: $pass"
    shift 2
    echo "Comment: $@"
}

# Loop through lines in your file and execute the adduser2 function with the line as argument.
while IFS= read -r l; do
    adduser2 $l;
done < file.txt
```

> Notes:
>
> - This will only work when you have no spaces in /path/to/home
> - You should consider to let the users set a new password on first login --> (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173708/how-do-i-force-a-user-to-change-a-password-at-the-first-time-login-using-ssh))
> - If you get a warning *unable to write random state*, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94445/using-openssl-what-does-unable-to-write-random-state-mean).

Comment: How can i do this without using any loops in a simple way. Is there any other simpler way without making own function?

Comment: you want to read information from a file, add users for each line, create a random password, set the password and output the password. That are a number of tasks and as long as there is no specialized app/script to do these, you need to script it on your own. Instead of the function, you could write a script in a file and instead of the loop you can use `xargs`. But to automate a task like this, I think these few lines of code are not a lot and it's actually quite simply to do ... So I don't see the problem.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
#apt-get install mkpasswd
#pass=$(openssl rand -base64 9)
#pass=ashik4331034
read word1 word2 word3 word4 < users.txt 
/usr/sbin/adduser --home $word2 --gecos "$word3 $word4" $word1 
#local pass=$(openssl rand -base64 5)
echo -e $pass | usr/bin/passwd $word1
#echo openssl rand -base64 9 | passwd $word1 > passwd.txt
#echo $word1:ashik4331034 | chpasswd
exit 0