# How to add users from text file into the unix system?

Tags: server, syslinux

I have a homework that require creating text file of users in unix and then reading each line of the file and actually adding them to the system?

How can this be done?
what i have done:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2LAK.png

however it's not working.

Comment: Homeworks are off topic here ;)

Comment: I thought so hard about this and still cant get how to change user (as a text) into an actual system user!

Comment: This should be closed in favour of the duplicate referenced below: https://askubuntu.com/q/1068434/459652

Comment: I have seen other homework problems receive favorable responses - the difference is that the person asking the question has shown the work that they have already done, and is asking what they are doing wrong, rather than asking "how to do this".  Can you amend your question with what you have already tried?

Comment: i must apologize but english is not my first language and things might have been understood wrongly.

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to make it look nice.

Comment: Ubuntu is not Unix, and Unix is off-topic here. If that's just a misunderstanding or typo, please [edit] the question to fix it. But if you are actually asking about Unix, please ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file with name: `text` witch contains all users name.

for example my text file contents
`usertemp`

this is only one test user name.

Then create bash script file like this

***run.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do 

useradd $line

done < text
```

Make the script `run.sh` runnable by type in terminal

`chmod +x run.sh`

At last run script with

`./run.sh`

Running above script may need root privileges.

`sudo ./run.sh`

Now these users cant log on because we have not assign any password to them.

***[ToDO]***

1. Assign password for created list of users.
2. Difference between using `adduser` and `useradd`, in this situation. [see](https://askubuntu.com/q/345974/678872)
3. Read username, password from only one file, text.

**[Related posts]**

1. https://askubuntu.com/a/1068448/678872

**[Edit]**

- Remove redundant `chmod 777 run.sh` as  [wjandrea](https://askubuntu.com/users/301745/wjandrea) said on comment, its only make the script readable writable and executable for everyone [see more](https://askubuntu.com/a/263566/678872)
- Use read command in script instead of `more`, to read line by line. I think its better in speed.

Comment: Why are you using `more` instead of just reading the file? i.e. `while read line; do ... done < text`. Also running `chmod 777` then `chmod +x` is redundant.